# How to do PostgreSQL Geometric query in rails console or model validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to determine if a point is inside a shape or polygon at the moment. I have a PostgreSQL query that returns a  boolean of true or false in the when i'm in my rails db. However, when I try to perform the same query in rails console. I get an error. What changes do I need to make so that the query can return a boolean of true or false in the rails console. I am referring to this link of geometric functions and operators https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-geometry.html

An example of my query in the rails db would be something like

```
select (circle '((0,0),2)' @> point '(1,1)');
```

When I try to run the same query in rails console, it gives me an error. of

```
'@>' is not allowed as an instance variable name
```

What do I need to change, so that the PostgreSQL query can be performed in the model validation or rails console